# Loop through JSON object and sum values by unique deep properties

Tags: javascript, express, underscore.js

Below is my JSON object (Below is just example of values I am interested in , in reality along with cost there are many other paramters)
I am trying to do this in  experss js and using underscore

```json
[
    {   
        "Cost":250,
        "author": { id :"2", name : "Joe" , workId: "5" }
    },
    {   
        "Cost":450,
        "author": { id :"2", name : "Joe" , workId: "6" }
    },
    {   
        "Cost":150,
        "author": { id :"3", name : "Tam" , workId: "7" }
    },
    {   
        "Cost":250,
        "author": { id :"2", name : "Joe" , workId: "8" }
    },
    {   
        "Cost":350,
        "author": { id :"3", name : "Tam" , workId: "9" }
    }
]
```

I want the output as below

> Joe 950 
> Tam 500

I tried this:

```
var iw={};
iw = Object.keys(myJsonObject.reduce((iw, curr) => {
    //iw[curr.author.id] = iw[curr.author.id]
    iw[curr.author.id].cost += parseInt(curr.cost);
    return iw;
}, iw)).map(key => iw[key]);
console.log("New ::"+iw);
```

But I didn't get what I hoped for:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cost' of undefined
    at Object.keys.myJsonObject.reduce (repl:3:7)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
New ::[object Object]
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a programming service. Please show an example of what you have tried. Also what language are you trying to accomplish this in?

Comment: var iw={};
            iw = Object.keys(myJsonObject.reduce((iw, curr) => {
              //iw[curr.author.id] = iw[curr.author.id]
              iw[curr.author.id].cost += parseInt(curr.cost);
              return iw;
            }, iw)).map(key => iw[key]);
            
            console.log("New ::"+iw);

Comment: Hi @Kevin , I am using this in express js

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74861/fraser) said

your original code had problem of not checking if that user already exists in the iw object already or not

your corrected solution:

```
myJsonObject = 
[
    {   
        "Cost":250,
        "author": { id :"2", name : "Joe" , workId: "5" }
    },
    {   
        "Cost":450,
        "author": { id :"2", name : "Joe" , workId: "6" }
    },
    {   
        "Cost":150,
        "author": { id :"3", name : "Tam" , workId: "7" }
    },
    {   
        "Cost":250,
        "author": { id :"2", name : "Joe" , workId: "8" }
    },
    {   
        "Cost":350,
        "author": { id :"3", name : "Tam" , workId: "9" }
    }
]

var iw={};
iw = myJsonObject.reduce((iw, curr) => {
iw[curr.author.name] ? iw[curr.author.name] += curr.Cost : iw[curr.author.name] = curr.Cost;
    return iw;
}, iw);

console.log(iw);
```

Result:

```
{Joe: 950, Tam: 500}
```

Comment: Also, the property was `Cost` with a uppercase C, not `cost` with a lowercase, and concatenating an object to a string gives you `[object Object]`, effectively hiding the information Mizan was interested in.

Comment: Thanks a ton , This works as expected . I was stuck on this for several hours.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a much cleaner way to do this, but a simple forEach would work. Obviously the output here is an object that contains the desired result.

```js
const data = [
    {   
        "Cost":250,
        "author": { id :"2", name : "Joe" , workId: "5" }
    },
    {   
        "Cost":450,
        "author": { id :"2", name : "Joe" , workId: "6" }
    },
    {   
        "Cost":150,
        "author": { id :"3", name : "Tam" , workId: "7" }
    },
    {   
        "Cost":250,
        "author": { id :"2", name : "Joe" , workId: "8" }
    },
    {   
        "Cost":350,
        "author": { id :"3", name : "Tam" , workId: "9" }
    }
]

let a = {};

data.forEach(e => a[e.author.name] ? a[e.author.name] += e.Cost : a[e.author.name] = e.Cost);

console.log(a);
```